# React Native navigation issue: Can't navigate to next screen on card press

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

The goal: to navigate from the MainScreen component to my DeliveryScreen component. I've an "onPress" function in the render func, where I specify the ListCard component. 
This func navigates to the DeliveryScreen, as listed in the App.js file (attached below the component), but when I press the card there's no response...
Would appreciate any suggestion. 
Thanks a lot.

```js
MainScreen- the component that navigates to DeliveryScreen:

// React
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Services
import DeliveryService from '../../services/DeliveryService';

// Vendors
import { Permissions, Location, Contacts }  from 'expo';

// Comps
import ListCard from '../ListCard/ListCard';

export class MainScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deliveries: [],
      locationResult: null, 
      locationRoute: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    DeliveryService.getData()
      .then(data => this.setState({
        deliveries: data
      }))
      this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  onPress = (delivery) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DeliveryScreen', {
      delivery, currLocation: JSON.parse(this.state.locationResult),
      handleCompletedDeliveries: this.handleCompletedDeliveries.bind(this)
    });
  }

  handleRouteResults = (result) => {
    this.setState({
      routeResult:result
    });
  }

  handleCompletedDeliveries = (id) => {
    var completedDeliveries = this.state.deliveries.slice();
    delivs.splice(completedDeliveries.findIndex(cd => cd.id === id), 1);
    this.setState({
      deliveries:completedDeliveries
    });
}

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        this.setState({
            locationResult: 'Access denied',
        });
    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    this.setState({ 
      locationResult: JSON.stringify(location) 
    });
  }

  render() {

    var icon = require('../../assets/img/location.png')
    var ham = require('../../assets/img/ham.png');
    var { deliveries } = this.state

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.nav}>
            <Image style={styles.ham} source={ham} />
            <Text style={styles.navTxt}>Future orders</Text>
            <Image style={styles.img} source={icon} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          {deliveries.map(delivery => {
            return (
              <ListCard key={delivery.id} data={delivery}
                onPress={(delivery) => {this.onPress(delivery)}}
              />
            )
          })}
          {/* Button should go here */}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  nav: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(66, 97, 144)',
    height: 60,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 7.3,
  },

  img: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24
  },

  ham: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40
  },
  navTxt: {
    width: 100,
    height: 26,
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 13.3
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  card: {
    width: 227.3,
    height: 100.6
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    paddingTop: 26,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16
  }
});

export default MainScreen;

App.js- where the navigations are specified: 

// React
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Comps 
import HomeScreen from './comps/HomeScreen/HomeScreen';
import DeliveryScreen from './comps/DeliveryScreen/DeliveryScreen';

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
    HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },

    DeliveryScreen: {
        screen: DeliveryScreen
    }

},
    { headerMode: 'none' }
)

export default RootNavigator
```

Comment: If you add a console log to your anonymous function in the `ListCard` `onPress` prop do you get a log? Wondering if your `ListCard` isn't calling the `onPress` prop that's passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have `this.handleCompletedDeliveries.bind(this)` in your `onPress`, however, you do not have `handleCompletedDeliveries` function defined in your `MainScreen`.

It seems that you needed to bind `handleCompleted` function instead. You should check the packager, it must be throwing an error to that context while your emulator/device may not be showing any errors.

**EDIT**

Additionally, you can

(a) Recheck `delivs.splice` in `handleCompletedDeliveries` function. `delivs` is not defined anywhere. Please do recheck rest of the code too for such small overlooks.

(b) Try debugging `onPress` (like @BenKane suggested) to see if it is being called at all.

(c) If it is being called correctly, try debugging each of the params you're passing in `onPress`.

(d) Also, do check the packager. More often than not, packager keeps throwing errors in the background while emulator/simulator/device does not. And errors in the packager are much more specific.

Comment: Yes, I see that and thanks, I fixed it and updated here. Yet that doesn't solve the problem which is earlier- I am not navigated to my DeliveryScreen when I press the card.

Comment: Please refer EDIT to my answer. Hope it helps.